# How to capture xmlhttprequests pending count in javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xmlhttprequest

As stated , How to capture xmlhttprequests pending count in javascript . I am using selenium with python.

Want to capture the number of xmlhttprequests are pending to complete.

Found an useful  link and tried the below javascript mentioned in the answer. However not understood properly and always getting the XMLHttpRequest.active as zero. Could anyone explain the logic or any other suggestions.

[Get count of network calls happening in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49048396/get-count-of-network-calls-happening-in-a-web-page)

from user https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887618/florent-b

I have included the javascript dynamically injecting to the screen.

```
jscript = ("(function() {" + 
"  var send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;" + 
"  var release = function(){ --XMLHttpRequest.active };" + 
"  var onloadend = function(){ setTimeout(release, 1) };" + 
"  XMLHttpRequest.active = 0;" +
"  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {" + 
"    ++XMLHttpRequest.active;" + 
"    this.addEventListener('loadend', onloadend, true);" + 
"    send.apply(this, arguments);" +
"  };})();")

print(jscript)

driver.execute_script(jscript)

isxmlhttpactive  = driver.execute_script("return (window.XMLHttpRequest.active);")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I have used the below logic to find any active xhr request is pending

```
            from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
            from requests import get
            from selenium import webdriver
            from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions
            import difflib
            import time


            path = r'c:/msedgedriver.exe'
            options = EdgeOptions()
            options.use_chromium = True
            options.add_argument('disable-gpu')
            driver = Edge(executable_path=path, options=options)
            driver.get(url)

            is_jquery_present = driver.execute_script("return (typeof jQuery != 'undefined');")

            if is_jquery_present == True:
                is_active_ajax_request  =   driver.execute_script("return ($.active);")
                

            while is_active_ajax_request >= 1:
                time.sleep(2)
                is_active_ajax_request =   driver.execute_script("return ($.active);")
```